# Can I write an HTML response from an .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but can I control the HTML response from a .htaccess file (Apache)?

In other words something like (psuedo code) `Write <!DOCTYPE html><html>...[etc]`

The reason I ask is because I would like to "take down" some sites in one "hit", but without replacing any files or having any other kind of holding page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer myself, certainly worked for what I needed:

```
ErrorDocument 503 "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>This website is undergoing maintenance</title></head><body style='font-family: sans-serif'><h1>This website is undergoing maintenance</h1></body></html>"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]
```

Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 2):

No its not possible to produce HTML content into a rewritten URI. However what you can do is to have a HTML file pre-written let's call it `outage.html` which will be placed in your DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Then enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and place this code on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteRule (?!^outage\.html$)^.*$ /outage.html [L,NC]
```

Whenever you want to bring the site down just uncomment above RewriteRule line by removing `#` and your site will just show `outage.html` to visitors for every URL.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will accept the answer as, presuming you are correct, the answer is, as you rightly say "no"!!

Comment: sorry dude, just found a way to do it - so have un-ticked your answer.

Comment: That's great to know, you can accept your own answer (I have already upvoted it :P)